# No space above bars when trying to customize y-axis in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to customize the y-axis in ggplot and can't find out how to make space above the bars. 
Here's a working example:

```
df <- data.frame(Place=rep(c('A','B','C','D'),each=2),
     Year=rep(c('14','15'),4), 
     Count=c(69400, 114443,  75922, 137006,  23062,  14504,  97440, 294008))
library('ggplot2')
ggplot(df,aes(x=Year,y=Count))+
       facet_wrap(~Place)+theme_bw()+
       geom_bar(stat = "identity",color="black")+
       scale_y_discrete(limits=c(0,100000,200000,300000), 
                        breaks=seq(0,300000,100000), 
                        labels=c("0", "100", "200","300"))
```

[image]

Any solutions?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "space above bars". Probably this is what you are looking for: `limits=c(0,100000,200000,350000)` and `labels=c("0", "100", "200","350")`.

Comment: The bar in the bottom right corner has no space over it so it looks like it protrudes into the bar above.

Comment: Why do you create a discrete scale? Your data is continuous and you should work with a continuous scale. You only want a space above the highest bar and no space below the bars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ggplot2` will automatically decide the best limits for your continuous y axis.
For the label, easier way is to transform your data if you want another unit (in your case, count divided by 1000). However, scale transformation and format is made easy with `scales` packages.

```
df <- data.frame(Place=rep(c('A','B','C','D'),each=2),
                 Year=rep(c('14','15'),4), 
                 Count=c(69400, 114443,  75922, 137006,  23062,  14504,  97440, 294008))
library('ggplot2')
ggplot(df,aes(x=Year,y = Count / 1000))+
  facet_wrap(~Place)+theme_bw()+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",color="black")
```

[image: exemple_1]

If your data have greater valuer (`> 300 000`), it will adjust. I add a year `16` for example:

```
df <- data.frame(Place=c(rep(c('A','B','C','D'),each=2), c('A','B','C','D')) ,
                 Year=c(rep(c('14','15'),4),rep("16", 4)),
                 Count=c(69400, 114443,  75922, 137006,  23062,  14504,  97440, 294008, 15000, 256000, 450000, 125000))
library('ggplot2')
ggplot(df,aes(x=Year,y = Count / 1000))+
  facet_wrap(~Place)+theme_bw()+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",color="black")
```

[image: exemple_2]

Comment: This creates a space above the highest bar. Thank you. 
But if the highest bar is raised a little bit over 300000 the labels do not change. I would also like to have the labels higher than the bars.

Comment: If you do not fix manually anything, it will adjust to your data. See my new example in my edit